# How to add font to the pubspec.yml for the dart server

Tags: dart, dart-server

I am using [pdf package](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) to generate a pdf file.
I want my custom font for the pdf file.
But I don't know how to add a font in the `pubspec.yaml` for the Dart project. This `pubspec.yaml` of the dart project doesn't have `flutter:`.

Comment: It looks like PdfTtfFont can construct a font from a byte data.  Just gotta get that into your code.

Answer (score 0):

From the comment by [Randal Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22483/randal-schwartz): `It looks like PdfTtfFont can construct a font from a byte data. Just gotta get that into your code.`

The solution is

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;

final fontFile = File('file path').readAsBytesSync();
final font = pw.Font.ttf(fontFile.buffer.asByteData());
```